# opening matlab on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, matlab, mate-terminal

I have successfully installed Matlab 2011 on my Ubuntu Mate 17.04 machine. The installation directory is /home/matlab

For instance, my installation directory looks like (see image below)
[image]

Now I read an article on Mathworks website that asks me to go to the bin directory and type matlab to open the application

The content of my bin directory looks like
[image]

I typed

```
matlab
```

The terminal output is

```
/usr/bin/matlab: 1: /home/snow/matlab/bin/util/oscheck.sh: /lib/libc.so.6: not found
/home/snow/matlab/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I tried other alternatives like

```
. matlab
bash matlab
./matlab
```

etc. but was not able to open the application.

Any help?

I have also given full permission (using chmod 777) to all files present in the bin directory.

Comment: There was no error throughout the installation process. it asked for the installation directory and it proceeded with it. Prior to this, there was an iso image that I mounted on /media/mathworks and then I simply followed the instructions given. I followed "https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94021-how-do-i-install-mathworks-products-using-an-iso-image"

Comment: Please add the output of `file ~/matlab/bin/matlab` and `uname -a`.

Comment: Possibly [Why do I get a libc.so.6: not found error when launching MATLAB in Ubuntu?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95976-why-do-i-get-a-libc-so-6-not-found-error-when-launching-matlab-in-ubuntu)

Comment: file ~/matlab/bin/matlab
/home/snow/matlab/bin/matlab: POSIX shell script, ASCII text executable

Comment: uname -a
Linux snow-Aspire-4738Z 4.10.0-21-generic #23-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 28 16:13:17 UTC 2017 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: I followed the link given by @steeldriver and since it was 32 bit system so I entered the command "sudo ln -s /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/libc.so.6 ". Even then, matlab is not opening. BTW assuming there was no such issue, what was I required to type "matlab" or ". matlab" or any other thing?

Comment: So can we assume that the reason you are trying to use such an old version of matlab is that it is the last one available for 32-bit Linux? Regardless, I'm not sure if it's supported for newer systems/kernels - see [Previous Releases: System Requirements and Supported Compilers](https://www.mathworks.com/support/sysreq/previous_releases.html)

Answer (score 1):

Basically, the error message is telling you a few files are missing (or else Matlab can't find them)....

```
/usr/bin/matlab: 1: /home/snow/matlab/bin/util/oscheck.sh: /lib/libc.so.6: not found
/home/snow/matlab/bin/glnx86/MATLAB: error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This means no matter what you do you won't be able to get the program to run without installing the necessary files or if the required packages are already installed but Matlab can't reference them you'll need to create the necessary symbolic links to them to allow the program to run. How this all works is largely dependent on your local installation and setup though hence the other person's question regarding your architecture. Read the following two links and things should become clearer to you...

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95976-why-do-i-get-a-libc-so-6-not-found-error-when-launching-matlab-in-ubuntu

https://askubuntu.com/questions/40416/why-is-lib-libc-so-6-missing

Answer (score 1):

While MATLAB is distributed as a compiled binary it requires a bunch of poorly documented dependencies. Depending on how minimal your Mate install is, you may not have all the correct dependencies. I created a [Matlab R2011b PKGBUILD for Arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/matlab-r2011b/) which lists the dependencies for Arch. These include: libxmu, libxp, libxpm, libxrandr, and libxtst. the PKGBUILD might help you identify the missing packages and files.

Comment: I tried installing these packages but Ubuntu is not recognizing them altogether. It just says that the concerned package could  not be located